# Promise function in WireMethod not working properly

Tags: javascript, query, lightning-web-components, cache

I am writing this wire method that when the data is loaded, it will trigger off a refresh of some other wire methods dependent on the results of this wire method. I do this by using a Promise and refreshApex method.

```
@track rels
@track relIds

@wire(getRels) wiredRels({error, data}) {
  if (data) {
    new Promise(() => {
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        data[i]["quizzes"] = [];
        this.rels.push(data[i]);
        this.relIds.push(data[i].Id);
        console.log('WIREDRELS - RelIds Length: ' + this.relIds.length);
      }
    }).then(() => {
      refreshApex(this.wiredQuizzes);
    })
  }
  else if (error) {
    // handle errors
  }
}

@wire(getQuizzes, { relIds: "$relIds"}) wiredQuizzes({error, data}) {
  console.log('WIREDQUIZZES - RelIds Length: ' + this.relIds.length);
  if (data) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.rels.length; i++) {
      for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (this.rels[i].Id === data[j].StudentCourseRelationship__c) {
          this.rels[i].quizzes.push(data[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if (error) {
    // handle errors
  }
}
```

There are two bugs that I'm running into:

- When the page that has this web component first loads, my debug console prints out:

```
WIREDQUIZZES - RelIds Length: 0
WIREDRELS - RelIds Length: 8
WIREDQUIZZES - RelIds Length: 8
```

Which is what I expect. But when the html goes to loop through a courses quizzes, it's not printing anything out, even though I was able to confirm that there were a few related quizzes. My guess is this is a caching issue from the first time `wiredQuizzes` was loaded it didn't have anything.

- My second issue is that when I go to reload the page, then the console prints out:

```
   WIREDQUIZZES - RelIds Length: 0
   WIREDQUIZZES - RelIds Length: 0
   WIREDRELS - RelIds Length: 8
```

Which tells me that the promise method isn't working, and it's running the `refreshApex` method before the promise finishes.

What do I need to do to chain together a queries

Comment: Interesting. I'd also like to know the answer with wire if someone chimes in. Is using two async awaits with standard promises not an option? It looks like it would be easier to control run order without a wire in this example.

Comment: @tsalb I was finally able to get it. I'll answer this question with a detailed description of how I handled the tiered queries.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part of your question, in wiredQuizzed you have to assign a new array to `rels` for the html to recognise that it has been changed.